# shorewall - VoIP - jitter buffer

Tags: networking, qos, voip, shorewall

I am using shorewall as my firewall and traffic shaping platform; however, I'm wondering what more I can do to help mitigate upstream jitter issues.  I have a fair amount of bandwidth, but the connection is not stable and enough so that jitter causes VoIP calls to be choppy.

I am already shaping the VoIP traffic and assigning it the highest priority.  I am planning to switch from guaranteeing 80% of the bandwidth to a set limit of 1Mb/s which should be more than sufficient.

Is there something more I can do, if so, at which level?  The problem with the call quality happens at both ends.  If I implement some sort of buffer on my end, that will fix the call choppiness when I attempt to hear others, but what can I do to fix others hearing me?

Comment: Possibly [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) somewhere in the upstream. Also, when shaping, make sure small packets (which is mostly ACKs etc) get high priority. Did you test that your shaping works correctly?

Comment: I'm still new to shaping, the only way I *know* my packets are shaped is by looking at the counters.  The counters look right, but other than that, no, I'm not monitoring and don't have a clue where to look.

Comment: That looks promising, I'm using FIFO, for my qdisc, so that doesn't seem right.  I will switch to SFQ or that + codel.